# Multiple spinners in ActionBar

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I use ActionBarSherlock, in which I set the navigation mode to 'list'

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
```

Is it possible to dynamically show a second spinner, depending on which item is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom action bar layout.

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom);
```

action_bar_custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner_collection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner_collection_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one..This may works...

Code:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
mSpinnerItem = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_spinner );
setupSpinner( mSpinnerItem );
```

Menu XML:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:visible="false"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER use NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST and onNavigationItemSelected it is not worth it !**

```
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId)

    You also cannot use menu's to do this:

   @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

due to inflation ordering.
```

Reasons:

```
(1) it generates a "hidden" spinner, for which you can not get the id.
(2) you cannot customize this spinner
(3) you save 30 lines of code, but are permanently limited if you want to add a second bi-directional spinner 
(4) not even in the special case of "simple code" (one spinner), you lose to much.
(5) you cannot use tabs.

the key is actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_custom);
and spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()...
for each spinner.
```

Trust me I lost hours trying each solution.